# Android data backend one way synchronisation

Tags: android, data-synchronization

I create a monitoring application who :

- if there is a network connection available : she sends periodically
  measurement data to the server using json
- if there is no network available, she stores the data in the sd card and sends it when the network connection is back.

Actually I use a circular buffer in memory that I empty when data are sent

Is there already something usefull in the framework or I have to write that completly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check [tape](http://square.github.com/tape/) library from square. I've never tried it but looks what you are looking for.